# Django form is never valid and hence doesnt save to database

Tags: python, django, web, django-models

I am creating  a registration model which has date,time(charfield with choices),customer and restaurant  .I need some help on why my instance is not saved even when I fill out my model form

**models.py**

```
class reservation(models.Model):
    TIMESLOTS = [
        ('11:00-1:00', '11:00-1:00'),
        ('01:00-3:00', '01:00-03:00'),
        ('03:00-05:00', '03:00-05:00'),
        ('05:00-07:00', '05:00-07:00'),
        ('07:00-09:00', '07:00-09:00')
    ]

    date=models.DateField(null=True)
    time=models.CharField(null=True,max_length=200,choices=TIMESLOTS)
    customer=models.OneToOneField(User,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    restaurant=models.OneToOneField(Restaurantdetails,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.restaurant.name
```

**forms.py**

```
class Reservationform(ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model=reservation
        fields=['date','time','restaurant']
```

**views.py**

```
def reservationcreator(request):
    form=Reservationform()

    if form.is_valid():
        form = Reservationform(request.POST)

        res=form.save()
        res.customer=request.user
        res.save()
        messages.success(request, 'reservation created')
        return redirect('menu')
    else:
        print('BS')
    context = {'form': form}

    return render(request,'userrestaurant/reservation.html',context)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your form will *never* be valid because you are supplying an empty form.  You need to add the `request.POST` data to that form *before* you validate it:

```py
def reservationcreator(request):
    form=Reservationform(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        res.customer=request.user
        res=form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'reservation created')
        return redirect('menu')
    else:
        print('BS')
    context = {'form': form}

    return render(request,'userrestaurant/reservation.html',context)
```

Answer (score 3):

A form that is *not* bounded, is *never* valid. A *bounded* form is a form that received data, for example through `request.POST` or `request.GET`; and `request.FILES`. You thus check the HTTP method, and depending on that initialize the form, so:

```
def reservationcreator(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Reservationform(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.customer = request.user
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'reservation created')
            return redirect('menu')
    else:
        form = ReservationForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'userrestaurant/reservation.html', context)
```

That being said, your view is a simple [**`CreateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView) and can be implemented with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.generic import CreateView

class ReservationCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = ReservationForm
    template_name = 'userrestaurant/reservation.html'
    success_url = reverse('menu')
    success_message = 'reservation created'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.customer = request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Comment: Is this *really* different than my answer? True, your *note* is totally valid, and your addition of request.FILES might be of help, but *seriously*, is my answer *wrong* given what the OP asked?  I apologize in advance if there is something I did not see, I *am* a relative novice, I understand that, and I understand that I make a lot of errors.  Again, apologies if I misconstrued what the OP was asking, or what you are doing differently to address the original question.

Comment: @raphael: you save the record twice, once without the customer, one with. If the field is non-nullable it will fail. `request.POST or None` is also a bit of an anti-pattern since it is possible that an empty `request.POST` is still valid (for example if all the checkboxes are unchecked) and no (other) fields are required: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/using-request-post-or-none.html

Comment: Thank you for your quick response..  Not surprisingly, you are correct, and I am in the wrong.  I've edited my answer.  That `request.POST or None` is an anti-pattern I will be investigating further, since I have seen it many times as a kind of new Django pattern.  But from your link I see that I may have to change a lot of my form handling code.  Thanks.